# Main page is redirecting on himself, .htaccess error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

so i have wordpress installed on website.
Today i've worked with .htaccess file, and after all main page is redirecting on himself (f.e. mysite.com/mysite.com), so i get 404 error page.
Have no idea what is going on, because hosting's team has made back-up and nothing has changed.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thank you!

Comment: why this? `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

Comment: anyway, it means any [only one character] after example.com/ to index.php

Comment: @xYuri have delited string, still have 404, but not template's customized: Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: what is the url that you trying to access?

Comment: and also check if the page you are trying to access is redirecting you to some where else, to debug redirects masks allow `301` redirects you will see the actual path you are redirected to. 
change `[L]` to `[L,R=301]`